# Fetch data from Google Analytics in Scalajs

Tags: intellij-idea, google-analytics-api, scala.js

I am trying to fetch the tracked data by Google Analytics of my web page using Google Analytics Java API into my scalajs program. I tried to follow its documentation and tried the following code :

Import statements :

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory
import com.google.api.services.analytics.{Analytics, AnalyticsScopes}
```

and the code is :

```
def gaTracker():Unit= {
val HTTP_TRANSPORT=new NetHttpTransport()
val JSON_FACTORY=new JacksonFactory()
val file = new File("/home/ishan/IdeaProjects/client_secret.json")
val apiEmail = "abc@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
val analyticsPrivateKeyFile: String = "/home/ishan/IdeaProjects/client_secret.p12"
val credential: GoogleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
  .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
  .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
  .setServiceAccountId(apiEmail)
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(analyticsPrivateKeyFile))
  .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.all())
  .build()

val analyticsService= new Analytics.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,JSON_FACTORY,credential).setApplicationName("tracker").build()
val startDate:String="2016-01-12"
val endDate:String="2016-15-12"
val metrics:String="ga:sessions,ga:timeOnPage"
val get=analyticsService.data().ga().get("ga:xxxxxx111",startDate,endDate,metrics)
val data=get.execute()
if (data.getRows()!=null){
  println("Fetched")
}
else{
  println("Not Fetched")
}
```

}

I added dependency in the build.sbt file :

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-analytics" % "v3-rev136-1.22.0"
```

But it is showing errors :

```
Referring to non-existent class com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory
Referring to non-existent class com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
```

I tried adding following dependencies also but nothing changed :

```
libraryDependencies+="com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client-jackson" % "1.18.0-rc"
```

Can someone guide me from here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use the JavaScript API to use it from Scala.js. You are using the server-side API...

Comment: @gzm0 Okay. I've implemented JavaScript API using the link : `https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started` and it is working fine as explained in the article. But I want the code to be done in scala.js. How can I convert it ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/